# Read 4 bytes of 8 byte field stored in a double

Tags: c++, c, pointers, types

I have a double.

```
double d
```

Unfortunately, it really contains a float, in its last 4 bytes. (reasons are complicated, no control over that). So the memory looks like this.

```
0x0000000012345678
```

I need to extract the last 4 bytes and store them in a float. I've tried a few different things but my best result so far is

```
float f = *(((float*) &d)) + 1);
```

Get double pointer of d, convert to float pointer, add 4 bytes, dereference.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Well, dirty code looks suitable for dirty works....

Answer (score 6):

There's certainly a more *portable* way:

```
float get(double d)
{
    float result;
    unsigned char * dst = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&result);
    unsigned char const * src = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const *>(&d);

    static_assert(sizeof(float) == 4);
    static_assert(sizeof(double) == 8);

    dst[0] = src[4];
    dst[1] = src[5];
    dst[2] = src[6];
    dst[3] = src[7];

    // or use std::memcpy or std::copy

    return result;
}
```

Comment: How can it be more *portable*?

Comment: @ikh It respects the [strict aliasing rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing), which OP's code doesn't.

Comment: Wouldn't that still be UB due to accessing a double's contents through pointers to a different type? Or is `char` somehow 'privileged'.

Comment: @IInspectable: char is privileged. E.g. the Char of Russia can alias anyone.

Comment: the Grand Duchess Any-aliaser ?

Comment: @IInspectable: Note this answer well  uses `unsigned char`, rather than `char`.  `unsigned char` has no padding and all bit patterns are well defined.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use a memcpy, something like :-

```
memcpy(&f, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&d)+4, sizeof (float));
```

Where f and d are the variables containing your double and float.

Answer (score 0):

C code

Variation on [@Kerrek SB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596781/kerrek-sb)

```
double d;
float f;
assert(2 * sizeof f == sizeof d);

memcpy(&f, (unsigned char*) &d + sizeof f, sizeof f);
```

Using unions

```
double d;
float f;
assert(2 * sizeof f == sizeof d);

union double_float {
  double d;
  float f[2];
} x
x.d = d;
f = x.f[1];
```

Comment: @Kerrek SB It is better when OP posts one language tag.  The answer clearly asserts `C`.  The `memcpy()` approach works in both `C/C++`.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38975546/2410359) does not compile in C even though it does not assert a C++ only solution.